# First Javascript Assignment: Can't seem to randomly generate password?

Tags: javascript, password-generator

I Seem to be at a loss, and cant proceed forward with this assignment. I have been trying to figure out how to randomly generate the password and then send the results to the passwordGeneration function.

```
   //Global Scope Password
var password = "";

var passwordGeneration = function() {
  // Call in Global Password here to send out at end
  password = "";

  //Create a function that will ask user for length of password. Note: Must be between 8 and 128 Chara long
  var lengthPassword = passwordLength();

  //Create a function that will determine all inclusions for Character Sets
  var passwordInclusions = charaInclusions();
};

//This is the function that will prompt for **password length**
var passwordLength = function() {
  //First, lets ask the user for the length of the password using a prompt
  var lengthPass = prompt("Enter Desired Length of New Password. Must Be Between 8 and 128 Characters Long.");

  //Next, lets validate the user input(Whether user entered invalid length or entered nothing at all)
  if (lengthPass < 8 || lengthPass > 128 || lengthPass === "") {
    alert("Invalid Length Entry. Length Must Be Between 8 and 128 Characters Long.")
    return passwordLength;
  }

  //This turns string into number. Note:refer to documentation if im still confused later.
  lengthPass = Math.floor(Number(lengthPass));

  //This will send data from this function to layout function!
  return lengthPass;
}

//Function That will determine included Character sets
var charaInclusions = function() {
  //String to send back inclusions at end
  var passwordInclusions = "";

  //Character Sets
  var lowerCase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var upperCase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var numbers = "0123456789";
  var specialChara = "~`!@#$%^&*+<?/;:(=)|{";

  //Ask to include characters(Confirms or Prompts?)
  var confirmLower = confirm("Include Lower Case Characters?");
  var confirmUpper = confirm("Include Upper Case Characters");
  var confirmNumber = confirm("Inlcude Numbers?");
  var confirmSpecial = confirm("Include Special Characters?");

  //Validate Selections
  if (confirmLower == true) {
    passwordInclusions += lowerCase;
  }
  if (confirmUpper == true) {
    passwordInclusions += upperCase;
  }
  if (confirmNumber == true) {
    passwordInclusions += numbers;
  }
  if (confirmSpecial == true) {
    passwordInclusions += specialChara;
  }

  //Send back results
  return passwordInclusions;
}

// Assignment Code Ending
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var password = generatePassword();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

  passwordText.value = password;

}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);
```

**How would i go about making the password generate randomly?
I got to here but im stuck. Im new to this and this is my first challenge.**

Comment: Where are you stuck? What is the question here? What goes wrong with the code?

Comment: I'm glad it helps, you can mark [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62670995/11908502) as an answer by using the grey mark (tick) icon beside the answer. For more information, you can read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 0):

So it's simply achievable with using `Math.random() * passwordInclusions.length` where `Math.random()` **will generate a random number (in range of `0-1` and its include `0` also) and `passwordInclusions.length` is the length of our `passwordInclusions` string**. Since the **result of the previous calculation will be decimal so we need to use `Math.floor` in order to get a round number** (integer). So the product of this calculation will give us a random index in our combined string.

```js
Math.floor(Math.random() * passwordInclusionsLength)
```

Finally, we can simply **select a char with [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt)**, since the previous calculation will give us a random index, so we can get a random char from our string.

```js
passwordInclusions.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * passwordInclusionsLength))
```

Then **with a traditional [for](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop, we can generate a password with the desired length** (`lengthPassword`) that we get from the user.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < lengthPassword; i++) {
  password += passwordInclusions.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * passwordInclusionsLength));
}
```

So the final code should be something like this:

```js
//Global Scope Password
var password = "";

var passwordGeneration = function() {
  // Call in Global Password here to send out at end
  password = "";

  //Create a function that will ask user for length of password. Note: Must be between 8 and 128 Chara long
  var lengthPassword = passwordLength();

  //Create a function that will determine all inclusions for Character Sets
  var passwordInclusions = charaInclusions();
  var passwordInclusionsLength = passwordInclusions.length;

  for (var i = 0; i < lengthPassword; i++) {
    password += passwordInclusions.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * passwordInclusionsLength));
  }

  return password;
};

//This is the function that will prompt for **password length**
var passwordLength = function() {
  //First, lets ask the user for the length of the password using a prompt
  var lengthPass = prompt("Enter Desired Length of New Password. Must Be Between 8 and 128 Characters Long.");

  //Next, lets validate the user input(Whether user entered invalid length or entered nothing at all)
  if (lengthPass < 8 || lengthPass > 128 || lengthPass === "") {
    alert("Invalid Length Entry. Length Must Be Between 8 and 128 Characters Long.")
    return passwordLength;
  }

  //This turns string into number. Note:refer to documentation if im still confused later.
  lengthPass = Math.floor(Number(lengthPass));

  //This will send data from this function to layout function!
  return lengthPass;
}

//Function That will determine included Character sets
var charaInclusions = function() {
  //String to send back inclusions at end
  var passwordInclusions = "";

  //Character Sets
  var lowerCase = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var upperCase = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  var numbers = "0123456789";
  var specialChara = "~`!@#$%^&*+<?/;:(=)|{";

  //Ask to include characters(Confirms or Prompts?)
  var confirmLower = confirm("Include Lower Case Characters?");
  var confirmUpper = confirm("Include Upper Case Characters");
  var confirmNumber = confirm("Inlcude Numbers?");
  var confirmSpecial = confirm("Include Special Characters?");

  //Validate Selections
  if (confirmLower == true) {
    passwordInclusions += lowerCase;
  }
  if (confirmUpper == true) {
    passwordInclusions += upperCase;
  }
  if (confirmNumber == true) {
    passwordInclusions += numbers;
  }
  if (confirmSpecial == true) {
    passwordInclusions += specialChara;
  }

  //Send back results
  return passwordInclusions;
}

// Assignment Code Ending
var generateBtn = document.querySelector("#generate");

// Write password to the #password input
function writePassword() {
  var password = passwordGeneration();
  var passwordText = document.querySelector("#password");

  passwordText.value = password;

}

// Add event listener to generate button
generateBtn.addEventListener("click", writePassword);
```

```html
<button id="generate">generate</button>
<input id="password" value="" />
```